# Edit .Bat File In C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Well, first of all my code :

```
protected void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string batname = edit.SelectedValue;
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("D:\\MPSite-Serv\\bats\\" + batname);

    string theedit = batedit.Text;
    sw.WriteLine(theedit);
    sw.Flush();
}
```

When I click on `button2` and try to write all of the text into the bat file, <strike>I get this result</strike> the bat file contains:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
```

Why is that?

I am using all of the following statements, if it helps:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get this result"? Where do you get that value from? What is `edit`?

Comment: in the .bat, when i press on "Edit".

Comment: that basically explains nothing. In the method you declare a variable (`batname`) which seems to get it's data from the property `SelectedValue` of the control instance called `edit`, just like `theedit` does with the control instance `batedit` and the property `Edit`. Also, can you try getting the `batname` and `theedit` variables so we can see if those are fetched correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx#Y2863

The problem is simple: sw.writeline expects a string. You are sending it a text object which gets turned into the aformentioned .ToString(); which means your line gets translated, loosely, into

```
sw.WriteLine(theedit.ToString());
```

if you look at the documentation for WebControls.TextBox... scroll down the list to the Method ToString()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx

What you need to do... is give it one string at a time (although I assume you could just give it the raw string from the textbox):

```
    using System.IO;

    namespace String_Writer
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string batname = "test.txt";
                string theedit = "Testing one two three four\n\nfive six seven eight.";
                using(StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("C:\\Users\\Kriis\\Desktop\\" + batname))
                {
                    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(theedit))
                    {
                        string line = string.Empty;
                        do
                        {
                            line = reader.ReadLine();
                            if (line != null)
                            {
                                sw.WriteLine(line);
                            }

                        } while (line != null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the type name of the textbox, which leads me to believe that your code rather looks something like:

```
sw.WriteLine(batedit);
```

I.e. you are sending the textbox object itself to be written to the file instead of the contents of its `Text` property. This will implicitly call the `ToString` method, which by default returns the type name of the object.

Also, you are not closing the `StreamWriter` properly, which might cause problems when you want to use it. You should call the `Close` method, and you don't have to call `Flush` before closing the `StreamWriter`. Alternatively you can put the `StreamWriter` in a `using` block, which would dispose it automatically, which will close it.

Comment: string batname = edit.SelectedValue;
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("D:\\MPSite-Serv\\bats\\" + batname);
        
        string theedit = batedit.Text;
        sw.WriteLine(theedit.ToString());
        sw.Close();

i did this, and its just dont do anything. 

i get black EDIT.

nothing,